# How to find minor currency price by using 7 major currencies

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency

I have price of all 7 major currencies.

> EUR/USD, USD/JPY, GBP/USD, USD/CHF, AUD/USD, USD/CAD, NZD/USD

Now what is the formula to find other minor currency prices by using major currency prices?

.

**I found on internet these formulas**

> EURUSD TO USDEUR

Formula: 1/EURUSD = USD/EUR

> EURUSD,EURJPY TO USDJPY

Formula: EURUSD/EURJPY = USDJPY

But how to find ZAR/USD price or any other currency pair by using 7  major currency?

**Update**

There must an algebraic formula, like, EURUSD divide with fix value 0.844 then divide it with USDCAD, Answer will always equal to ZARUSD etc.

Comment: You'd need a conversion rate from one of the other major countries to ZAR to find USDZAR. How do you expect to get an unrelated currency rate from just the major rates?

Comment: What makes you think that determining the ZAR/USD price by using 7 major currency is even possible??

Comment: i believe its possible, showing by its name, "major currency" these 7 are major. And also other minor currencies always move up/down when major currency move.

Comment: I need this formula to do some programming

Comment: When solving algebraic equations, you need each representation of each variable.  You have that for 7 variables.  You are asking for the value of an 8th variable which is not represented.   It cannot be calculated.

Comment: If it was possible to calculate a minor currency using only the relative values of the major currencies, wouldn't that imply that all minor currencies have the same value?

Comment: what if i have 140 currencies all (USD) etc/USD except ZAR/USD, so how to get ZAR in that situation?

Comment: If there's relevant information in the video please include it in the question.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I have removed the link which I believe to be spam affiliated with the asker.

Answer (score 4):

Given the 7 major currencies, you can only find MAJORCURRENCY/OTHERMAJIRCURRENCY!

if you need to compute ZAR/USD, you are obliged to use as input ZAR/MAJORCURRENCY then use your final formula.

Answer (score 2):

> There must an algebraic formula, like, EURUSD divide with fix value 0.844 then divide it with USDCAD, Answer will always equal to ZARUSD etc.

No, there is no such formula. If you don't have any information about ZAR, then you cannot calculate ZAR/USD. It's as simple as that.

As an analogy, consider the following puzzle:

> There are two brothers: an older brother and his younger brother. The two brothers don't have any other siblings. The older brother was born on the 7th day of the month. What day of the month was the younger brother born on?

The puzzle is obviously impossible to solve, because there are lots of families just like this one in the world, and among those families, different younger brothers were botn on different days of the month.

Therefore, if someone tells you that they can solve the puzzle, you know for a fact that they're certainly lying.

Likewise, there are lots of currencies just like ZAR in the world, and among those currencies, different ones have different values in relation to USD. Therefore, if someone tells you they have a formula for ZAR/USD without using any information about ZAR, you and I know for a fact that they're certainly lying.